# Severe crashing / freezing / hanging issue on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: freeze, crash, system, 23.04

I've been working on moving over to linux for the past 3 days and tried multiple distributions. All of them had this same problem I'm describing. Whenever I start up my laptop it flashes a few bios warnings before moving on. I can get into and work with Ubuntu just fine until it randomly freezes. These freezes are inconsistent in how bad they are. Sometimes I can just kill and restart the DE and it goes back to normal. Sometimes I can't, but I can still move the cursor, and sometimes even sysreq combos don't work. I did make sure they were all active when not frozen. Usually a few minutes after starting Firefox, it will crash hard, and sometimes random interactions will cause the whole system to go into lock up. I have really no idea what it could possibly be. [Here's the hardware probe with all my hardware information + logs for my device](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=7f11156b87), and [here's a dmesg output after firefox crashed and right before everything else did](https://pastebin.com/LmbFzGEt). Of note, I have to use kernel 6.2+ due to the wireless card not being supported on previous versions

It's painful. I've gone through all the things I can find related to my problem on this sit and nothing has helped. Everything worked perfectly on windows though so I don't know what it would be. My system has frozen 3 times while writing this. A new thing happened as well. The keyboard input had a latency of around 20 seconds before inputs were "enacted". After that, I clicked the settings icon in the top bar and that hard froze everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may want to look at your swap configuration in relation to your memory size. Please edit your question and add the output of `free -m`.

Comment: The dmesg output shows multiple hardware errors, don't know if there is much to be done.

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab fallocate` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I fixed it! I did a few things, so it really could be any of them:

- Updating Kernel version to 6.3.2 (Didn't fix)
- Updating Kernel version to 6.4-rc1 (Might have fixed) ([link to deb files](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v6.4-rc1/))
- Switching away from using the NVIDIA On-Demand PRIME profile in `nvidia-settings` to NVIDIA Performance mode (Might have fixed)
- Switching from the snap Firefox to the Deb version

In my testing, both wayland and x11 work great

Thanks for all the ideas guys!

Comment: Thanks, for me the Performance mode was the solution.

Comment: I was seeing similar issues, and I changed from an nvidia card to amd and still had the crashes (but with wayland it was just crash to login screen thankfully).

Replacing snap firefox with Deb version is what appears to have fixed this for me - something about the firefox snap was making things unstable. Not 100% but haven't had the same issue since.

Comment: In addiion to this,  Updating BIOS works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am in 23.04. Same issue, random crashes. At the beginning though it was the SSD drive about to die, checked using smartmontools, everything reported right, updated to the last nVidia driver 535 from the proprietary drivers, Upgraded to kernel 6.4.3, no joy...

However noticed the laptop (HP Pavilion 15-csxxx, using NVIDIA GeForce GTX MX150) was all the times with fans running very fast, and a lot of heat coming from the sides. Installed lm-sensors and from the command line using sensors, noticed how the cores sometimes raised up to 85°C (185°F) and the ACPI driver up to 95°C (203°F)... in those events, happening randomly, there was a thermal cut, because the fans were not able to dissipate all the heat, and the system crashed, time and again...

Looking at some comments in forums, about nVidia GPU and new drivers v535.x problems,  I decided to replace it by OpenSource driver noveau... And presto! All troubles disappeared . No more crashes, nor raising temps in HW, even if I run VBox virtual machines or do a video format conversion. Temps are stable at around 39°C (102°F)
I'll do what was suggested by some other forums: Not install any nVidia-related drivers until the upgrade looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might not apply to everyone, but I had the same problems and discovered through System Monitor that multiple processes called `fossilize_replay` were eating away at my memory.

It turns out that this is Steam's Vulkan Shader Pre-caching. Opening Steam, clicking `Steam -> Settings -> Downloads`, scrolling down and unchecking "Allow background processing of Vulkan shaders" **immediately** solved all of the freezing problems and those processes went away!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar crashes and figured out the problem was my Nvidia GPU. Nvidia drivers re not compatible on Ubuntu. I switched to my Intel GPU and crashes are gone. For Ubuntu just use AMD or Intel. Problem is AMD are all power hogs and will wreck a regular office machine that does not have 500 PSU or greater. I don't do gaming so  I don't even need a great GPU. Just no more crashing is all I care about now. Lesson learned. Make sure you only buy a computer that can support the non-Nvidia GPU of your choice. That means find out how much power your GPU REALLY will require, not what the manufacturer claims.